# How to sleep/wait in for-loop after each pass?

Tags: python, for-loop, sleep, wait, pexpect

I have a for loop which pushes config to network devices via pexpect, here's the beginning of my script:

```
with open("devices.txt") as ips:
    all_ips = [x.rstrip() for x in ips]
    for ip in all_ips:
        child = pexpect.spawn ('telnet '+ ip)
```

How do I force the script to wait/sleep after it runs the commands on each device listed in my file 'devices.txt' ?

I understand it's in the time module, but not sure how to bring this into my loop so that it waits for a period after each pass through the loop?

```
import time
time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: I'm confused, what's wrong with time.sleep?

Answer (score 3):

Sleep in the loop:

```
import time

with open("devices.txt") as ips:
    all_ips = [x.rstrip() for x in ips]

for ip in all_ips:
    child = pexpect.spawn ('telnet '+ ip)
    time.sleep(1) # sleep here
```

The program will sleep for 1 second after executing `child = pexpect.spawn ('telnet '+ ip)` for each `ip` in `all_ips`.